# Effect of WiFi hotspot usage on mobile phone circuitry

Tags: wifi, mobile

Despite the fact that mobile phones come in wide a variaary and form different suppliers and with different software, most mobiles todays have a WiFi hotspot feature that can convert a mobiles' internet connection into a WiFi SSID.

Typically, mobiles phones have a WiFi supportable chip that adds WiFi to phones. People ( including myself) use the above said feature ( hotspot) feature to access internet from our laptops using the mobiles internet.

For uses who don't download heavily and only do browsing, I would like to know if the said feature can tremendously have an impact on the phones lifetime. Especially on its base-band processor, wifi soc etc.

A second question is if I take a video call over Viber, Skype or hangouts I will be using phones camera. Thus the phone is required to process the video at the same time transmit it. Wouldn't it be much better if I use a hotspot and then use my PC to run these software? ( wouldn't that allow mobile to do less processing thus less heat and more lifetime)

My questions are applicable to common phones. I do not mean satellite phones.

I love my phone and I am a tech geek. I am just wondering if someone can shred some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such activities will have an effect on how long the battery charge lasts, which may require more charging cycles in a given period of time. This may reduce the lifetime of the battery somewhat.

However, there will be no measurable effect on the lifetime of the other components inside the phone.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of power used, the battery life (talk time) and recharge cycles (replace battery).

You will have to characterise the power needed for

Phone Wi-Fi Hotspot
   **vs**
Camera and extra video codec processing if your phone processor is sped up to handle the extra task.

The wear and tear on silicon in your phone or PC is so low that it is usually safe to ignore while wear on your chemical battery is real.